# Find a maximal set of independent equations in a system of non-linear equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given a system of non-linear algebraic equations. Is there some general method to find a maximal set of independent equations in this system? For example, $\{x^2+y^2=1, x = y\}$ is a maximal set of independent equations in the system $x^2+y^2=1$, $x = y$, $2x^2=1$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gröbner_basis